Regarding Global Variable Declaration In Angular 17
I want to declare my baseurl as a global variable in my angular project without importing any module. I  want to access the value whenever I type baseurl in any component or service. currently, I am passing through the URL in child which is shown below
{
  path: '',
  component: DashboardComponent,
  canActivate: \[authGuard\],
  data: { baseurl: 'https://192.168.1.10:45457/api/' },
  children: \[
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashComponent },
  { path: 'audit', component: AuditComponent },
  { path: 'Person', component: PersonComponent },
  ...... 
}

Please guide me through this.

So, what is the question?

It's not a good idea to declare a global variable like:
const API_URL = 'https://192.168.1.10:45457/api/';

Because when you use it, it's unclear from where it originates on the source code.
Instead you can declare a export variable on the main.ts like this:
export const API_URL  = 'https://192.168.1.10:45457/api/';

Then on the place you want to use, you can do:
import { API_URL } from './src/main';

Another way to do this, is to use environments which is a good way, to configure the URL based on which environment you are on, development or production, etc.
Creating environment -> Answer by Andrew Allen for reference

Is There any other way in which i can be able to access  the   API_URL without  importing the module in each component because in my current project there are lots of components are declared and each one needs a  API_URL so it would be a hessel if i have to import to access the  API_URL in each component

@Vivek just do the first line of code and use it on all the components, else declare it on the window['base_url'] = 'something' and access it! But its not recommended, in future it will be a mess!
